# Adding values from small matrices to a bigger one based on their index/column names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sympy

I have four 4x4 matrices (K1, K2, K3, K4) and their values are going to be added in a large 8x8 matrix K. As can be seen below each one has index- and column names and I want to add values from the small matrices based on their index/column names to correspond with the larger one. For example: from K1 (v1, v1) equals to 1 and therefor 1 should be added to (v1, v1) in the large matrix.

So far the 4 small matrices are created based on some manually inserted values/variables from the given math problem so the index/column names can therefor change in the next problem. There will always be four 4x4 matrices but their index/column names will vary between the ones in the large matrix.
Is it maybe possible to create a for-loop with if-statements to go over the names of the index/column names of the small matrices to where to add what in the large? I'm stuck and grateful for all the help I can get!

Here is the code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
from sympy import Eq, solve_linear_system, Matrix
from numpy import linalg
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sy.init_printing()

A, E, L, Rx, P, rot3, rot2 = sy.symbols("A, E, L, Rx, P, rot3, rot2", real=True)

r2 = round(2**(1/2), 2)
r3 = round(3**(1/2), 2)

x1_e1 = 0
x2_e1 = 0
y1_e1 = 0
y2_e1 = L
L1 = L
c1 = (x2_e1 - x1_e1) / L1
s1 = (y2_e1 - y1_e1) / L1
column_names1 = ['u1', 'v1', 'u3', 'v3']
row_names1 = column_names1

x1_e2 = (2*L)/r3
x2_e2 = (r3*L)/2
y1_e2 = 0
y2_e2 = L/2
L2 = L/(r3)
c2 = (x2_e2 - x1_e2) / L2
s2 = (y2_e2 - y1_e2) / L2
column_names2 = ['u2', 'v2', 'u4', 'v4']
row_names2 = column_names2

x1_e3 = ((r3*L))/2
x2_e3 = 0
y1_e3 = L/2
y2_e3 = L
L3 = L
c3 = (x2_e3 - x1_e3) / L3
s3 = (y2_e3 - y1_e3) / L3
column_names3 = ['u4', 'v4', 'u3', 'v3']
row_names3 = column_names3

x1_e4 = 0
x2_e4 = (r3*L)/2
y1_e4 = 0
y2_e4 = L/2
L4 = L
c4 = (x2_e4 - x1_e4) / L4
s4 = (y2_e4 - y1_e4) / L4
column_names4 = ['u1', 'v1', 'u4', 'v4']
row_names4 = column_names4

def calc_K() :

    A1 = A
    E1 = E
    AEL1 = round(((A1*E1)/L1)/((A*E)/L), 2)
    K_1 = np.zeros((4,4),dtype=np)
    K_1[0][0] = round(c1**2, 2)
    K_1[0][1] = round(c1*s1, 2)
    K_1[0][2] = round(-(c1**2), 2)
    K_1[0][3] = round(-(c1*s1), 2)
    K_1[1][0] = round(c1*s1, 2)
    K_1[1][1] = round(s1**2, 2)
    K_1[1][2] = round(-(c1*s1), 2)
    K_1[1][3] = round(-(s1**2), 2)
    K_1[2][0] = round(-(c1**2), 2)
    K_1[2][1] = round(-(c1*s1), 2)
    K_1[2][2] = round(c1**2, 2)
    K_1[2][3] = round(c1*s1, 2)
    K_1[3][0] = round(-(c1*s1), 2)
    K_1[3][1] = round(-(s1**2), 2)
    K_1[3][2] = round(c1*s1, 2)
    K_1[3][3] = round(s1**2, 2)
    K__1 = (AEL1 * K_1)
    K1 = pd.DataFrame(K__1, columns=column_names1, index=row_names1)
    print('')
    print('---------- K1 ----------')
    print('AE/L *')
    print(K1)
    print('')

    A2 = A
    E2 = E
    AEL2 = round(((A2*E2)/L2)/((A*E)/L), 2)
    K_2 = np.zeros((4,4),dtype=np)
    K_2[0][0] = round(c2**2, 2)
    K_2[0][1] = round(c2*s2, 2)
    K_2[0][2] = round(-(c2**2), 2)
    K_2[0][3] = round(-(c2*s2), 2)
    K_2[1][0] = round(c2*s2, 2)
    K_2[1][1] = round(s2**2, 2)
    K_2[1][2] = round(-(c2*s2), 2)
    K_2[1][3] = round(-(s2**2), 2)
    K_2[2][0] = round(-(c2**2), 2)
    K_2[2][1] = round(-(c2*s2), 2)
    K_2[2][2] = round(c2**2, 2)
    K_2[2][3] = round(c2*s2, 2)
    K_2[3][0] = round(-(c2*s2), 2)
    K_2[3][1] = round(-(s2**2), 2)
    K_2[3][2] = round(c2*s2, 2)
    K_2[3][3] = round(s2**2, 2)
    K__2 = (AEL2 * K_2)
    K2 = pd.DataFrame(K__2, columns=column_names2, index=row_names2)
    print('')
    print('---------- K2 ----------')
    print('AE/L *')
    print(K2)
    print('')

    A3 = A
    E3 = E
    AEL3 = round(((A3*E3)/L3)/((A*E)/L), 2)
    K_3 = np.zeros((4,4),dtype=np)
    K_3[0][0] = round(c3**2, 2)
    K_3[0][1] = round(c3*s3, 2)
    K_3[0][2] = round(-(c3**2), 2)
    K_3[0][3] = round(-(c3*s3), 2)
    K_3[1][0] = round(c3*s3, 2)
    K_3[1][1] = round(s3**2, 2)
    K_3[1][2] = round(-(c3*s3), 2)
    K_3[1][3] = round(-(s3**2), 2)
    K_3[2][0] = round(-(c3**2), 2)
    K_3[2][1] = round(-(c3*s3), 2)
    K_3[2][2] = round(c3**2, 2)
    K_3[2][3] = round(c3*s3, 2)
    K_3[3][0] = round(-(c3*s3), 2)
    K_3[3][1] = round(-(s3**2), 2)
    K_3[3][2] = round(c3*s3, 2)
    K_3[3][3] = round(s3**2, 2)
    K__3 = (AEL3 * K_3)
    K3 = pd.DataFrame(K__3, columns=column_names3, index=row_names3)
    print('')
    print('---------- K3 ----------')
    print('AE/L *')
    print(K3)
    print('')

    A4 = A
    E4 = E
    AEL4 = round(((A4*E4)/L4)/((A*E)/L), 2)
    K_4 = np.zeros((4,4),dtype=np)
    K_4[0][0] = round(c4**2, 2)
    K_4[0][1] = round(c4*s4, 2)
    K_4[0][2] = round(-(c4**2), 2)
    K_4[0][3] = round(-(c4*s4), 2)
    K_4[1][0] = round(c4*s4, 2)
    K_4[1][1] = round(s4**2, 2)
    K_4[1][2] = round(-(c4*s4), 2)
    K_4[1][3] = round(-(s4**2), 2)
    K_4[2][0] = round(-(c4**2), 2)
    K_4[2][1] = round(-(c4*s4), 2)
    K_4[2][2] = round(c4**2, 2)
    K_4[2][3] = round(c4*s4, 2)
    K_4[3][0] = round(-(c4*s4), 2)
    K_4[3][1] = round(-(s4**2), 2)
    K_4[3][2] = round(c4*s4, 2)
    K_4[3][3] = round(s4**2, 2)
    K__4 = (AEL4 * K_4)
    K4 = pd.DataFrame(K__4, columns=column_names4, index=row_names4)
    print('')
    print('---------- K4 ----------')
    print('AE/L *')
    print(K4)
    print('')

    column_names5 = ['u1', 'v1', 'u2', 'v2', 'u3', 'v3', 'u4', 'v4']
    row_names5 = column_names5
    KK__1 = np.zeros((8,8),dtype=np)
    KK_1 = pd.DataFrame(KK__1, columns=column_names5, index=row_names5)
    print(KK_1)
```

This is now the output:

```
---------- K1 ----------
AE/L *
   u1  v1 u3  v3
u1  0   0  0   0
v1  0   1  0  -1
u3  0   0  0   0
v3  0  -1  0   1

---------- K2 ----------
AE/L *
        u2      v2      u4      v4
u2   0.432  -0.761  -0.432   0.761
v2  -0.761    1.30   0.761   -1.30
u4  -0.432   0.761   0.432  -0.761
v4   0.761   -1.30  -0.761    1.30

---------- K3 ----------
AE/L *
       u4     v4     u3     v3
u4   0.75  -0.43  -0.75   0.43
v4  -0.43   0.25   0.43  -0.25
u3  -0.75   0.43   0.75  -0.43
v3   0.43  -0.25  -0.43   0.25


---------- K4 ----------
AE/L *
       u1     v1     u4     v4
u1   0.75   0.43  -0.75  -0.43
v1   0.43   0.25  -0.43  -0.25
u4  -0.75  -0.43   0.75   0.43
v4  -0.43  -0.25   0.43   0.25

---------- K ----------
   u1 v1 u2 v2 u3 v3 u4 v4
u1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
v1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
u2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
v2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
u3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
v3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
u4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
v4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Desired output:

```
------------------------ K ------------------------
     u1    v1    u2    v2    u3    v3    u4    v4
u1  0.75  0.43   0     0     0     0   -0.75  -0.43
v1  0.43  1.25   0     0     0    -1   -0.43  -0.25
u2   0     0    0.25 -0.43   0     0   -0.25   0.43
v2   0     0   -0.43  0.75   0     0    0.43  -0.75
u3   0     0     0     0     0     0   -0.75   0.43
v3   0    -1     0     0     0    -1    0.43  -0.25
u4 -0.75 -0.43 -0.25  0.43  0.25  0.43  1.75  -0.43
v4 -0.43 -0.25  0.43 -0.75  0.43 -0.25 -0.43   1.25
```

Comment: Can you share the rules for merging K1, K2, K3, K4 into K ?  For example, how is k[v4, v4] calculated from K1, K2, K3, K4?

Comment: The original problem is based on a truss with 4 elements and K1, K2, K3, K4 are the stiffness matrices of each element. The truss has 4 elements and 4 nodes. Each element is a beam with 1 node at each end where displacements occur. In this problem element 1 contains nodes 1 and 3 where the displacements u1, v1 and u3, v4 occur. So the matrix for element 1 (K1) contains u1, v1, u3, v3. The large matrix K therefor contains u1 v1 ... u4 v4 to include all displacements of all nodes for all elements. So in K(u1, u1) add all values from the small matrices that include (u1, u1), from K1,K4 here.

Comment: I was wondering how you were using names when dealing with numpy matrices.  Turns out you are really using `pandas`.  As written it is going to be hard to generalize this code.  Usually problems like this use numeric indices and mappings.  Years ago I wrote finite element code in MATLAB using its sparse matrices (because there are lots of zeros in larger problems)..

Comment: @alexjette, Can you explain how `K(v4, v4)` is calculated? Is it `K2(v4, v4) + K3(v4, v4) + K4(v4, v4)` ? If yes, then shouldn't `K(v4, v4)` be 1.8 (1.3 + 0.25 + 0.25) ? How is `K(v4, v4)`  `1.25` ?

Comment: @tpk You are right, it should be 1.8, not 1.25! My bad, sorry.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay! Have you done any finite element problems in python? I don´t have room for matlab on my computer.. Yeah the matrices can really get big but in our case they are small enough to calculate by hand but i figured it would be nice to make a program doing it for me.

Comment: @alexjette Sounds cool. Let me take a jab at it.